# AWS, Elasticsearch, Filebeat: Apply index policy to index pattern instead of specific index

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, filebeat

I am working on AWS's Elasticsearch(7.9), where we are pushing logs via filebeat. To remove old logs, I have a policy, but filebeat everyday creates new indexes, I have a single index pattern filebeat-*.

Is there a way to apply index lifecycle policy to a given pattern?

Or is there a way to inform filebeat to use a single index, and keep pushing on it.

Screenshot for issue:

[image]

As you can see, only 1 index has policy, I cannot login everyday and apply policy to new indexes, not practical. :-) Any help would be nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

#### Add policy to indices

```
curl --user "user:password" -X POST "https://your_elasticsearch_url/_opendistro/_ism/add/sandbox-2021.01.28" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "policy_id": "cleanup_old_indices"
}' | jq -r
```